# Power calculation for TSSEM or Meta-analytic SEM

Tags: meta-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, statistical-power

I am wondering about power calculations for Cheung's metaSEM/TTSEM.

I assume Stage 2 SEM is where having too few studies/small sample sizes becomes problematic. Is there a way to run an a priori power calculation? would this be the same as a general power calculation for a SEM? any help much appreciated.